# Making IHttpContextAccessor readonly in in class but adding header in current request

Tags: c#, httprequest, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a class where I am injecting `IHttpContextAccessor` in constructor and declaring local variable to use it letter. Like below

```
public class Test
{
     private IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
     Test(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
     {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
     }
}
```

In the same class I am adding some values in header using the variable `httpContextAccessor` as below

```
 public void AddRequestHeadder()
 {
    httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryAdd("key", clientId);
    httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryAdd("key1", clientSecret);
 }
```

So in my opinion I am modifying the variable "httpContextAccessor" and it should not be readonly in the class where I have declared it.

But on **Sonar Cloud** it is showing a code smell and suggesting to make the field readonly.

 So my question is if I make it `readonly, like below

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
```

will it let me to modify the header inside it.

Comment: Why shouldn't the _field variable_ `httpContextAccessor` be `readonly`?

Comment: @Llama because I am modifying the variable?

Comment: You're not though. You're modifying the instance that it holds. If you were modifying the variable you might be doing something like `httpContextAccessor = someNewValue();` at the end of `AddRequestHeader()` (as an example), but you're not.

Comment: @Llama So you want to say if I have a class `A` which has a class `B` object inside and if I modify the  `B's` instance which is inside `A` then I am not modifying `A` is it like this?

Comment: Indeed. The code in your question is actually modifying `Headers`.

Comment: `readonly` isn't transitive in C#, generally. You are not modifying the field but some sub-objects its object graph contains.

Answer (score 2):

From the [`readonly` keyword docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) states:

> In a field declaration, `readonly` indicates that **assignment to the field can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class.** A readonly field can be assigned and reassigned multiple times within the field declaration and constructor.

Assignment is when you set a variable to a value. For example:

```
int a;
a = 5; // assign the value 5 to a
```

You are not reassigning `httpContextAccessor` anywhere in your code, so you can safely mark it as `readonly`.

Note that if you had a value type (instead of a reference type as you currently do), marking it as `readonly` would also make it immutable. As per the docs:

> A `readonly` field can't be assigned after the constructor exits. This rule has different implications for value types and reference types:
>
> - Because value types directly contain their data, a field that is a readonly value type is immutable.

In the case of your reference type, the only thing that becomes immutable is the pointer<sup>1</sup> to the object in memory. You can make changes to the object it points to as you see fit:

> Because reference types contain a reference to their data, a field that is a `readonly` reference type must always refer to the same object. That object isn't immutable. The `readonly` modifier prevents the field from being replaced by a different instance of the reference type. However, the modifier doesn't prevent the instance data of the field from being modified through the read-only field.

<sub><sup><sup>1</sup> It's not a pointer in the sense of C, and C++, etc. Such pointers do exist in C#, but that's not what I mean here.</sup></sub>